# Create array of flow of data

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have an app that connects via Bluetooth to an external device (I use BLE-PLX). In this way I read a flow of data from the device. (it is a continuous flow of data like acceleration, pressure, etc.. ). I need to pass these data in array (also an array for each data.) to write them in the DB in a second moment. How can I do to pass these data in arrays?

For example this is my code, that I use to read and print in the app the data.

```
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.manager = new BleManager();
    this.state = {
      time: null,
// Values from Left Device
      acc: [],
      gyr: [],
      mg: [],
// Values from Right Device
      acc_dx: [],
      gyr_dx: [],
      mg_dx: []
}
// Connection to Device
//.......


 async setupNotifications2(device) {
    const service = this.serviceGeneral();
    device.monitorCharacteristicForService(
      service,
      this.AccGyrMg,
      (error, characteristic) => {
        if (error) {
          this.error(error.message);
          return;
        }
const acc = [2, 4, 6].map(index => {
          const hex = Buffer.from(characteristic.value, "base64")
            .readInt16LE(index)
            .toString(16);
          return Number.parseInt(hex, 16);
        });
}

 render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>Left Device: </Text>
        <Text>{"Acc:" + this.state.acc.join(" ")}</Text>
        <Text>-----------</Text>
        <View>
          <Text>Right Device: </Text>
          <Text>{"Acc:" + this.state.acc_dx.join(" ")}</Text>
        </View>
        <View>
          <TouchableOpacity
            style={[style.button, style.buttonOK]}
            onPress={() =>
              this.stopConnection(this.state.deviceName1, this.state.deviceName2)
            }
          >
            <Text style={style.buttonTesto}>Stop</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </View>
```

And I should create this array with the flow of data when the user click on a stop button. (At the moment the "this.stop" cancel the bluetooth connection, but I would only stop the read of data).

EDIT (in response of mTv)

1. I read the data from the device and print in the app, and the data look like this for "{"Acc:" + this.state.acc.join(" ")}" :

> 201:-952:-1565,
>   166:-759:-1457,
>   40:135:-591:-1376,
>   60:106:-471:-1312,
>   80:82:-387:-1259
>   ......

They change If the external device is moved. (they are not static but are constantly changing )

2. I Want create an array that contains all the data that are read, Like:

> ```
> "Acc": [
>     [
>       "201:-952:-1565",
>       ":166:-759:-1457",
>       "135:-591:-1376",
>       "106:-471:-1312",
>       "82:-387:-1259", 
>        //......
>        ]]
> ```

3. The user shouldn't see this data, so they are used only from me to read if I register in the right way these data and and then fill them on db.

Thank you so much.

Comment: can you please add complete code? thanks

Comment: What do you need??? For example I would pass the values from acceleration ("acc" variable).

Comment: Yes of course but you can't anyway run my code :( because I connect to external devices throughts bluetooth. This is the only reason why I ask you if you need other parts.

Comment: Can't you just put it into its respective array? Like `this.setState({acc: [...data]})`? I don't understand the issue here:S. What does the data look like? How do you receive it from your devices? Where and how do you want the data?

Comment: @mTv Ok I try to explain myself better. Basically I have an external device to which I connect via bluetooth. From this device I read the data sent to me. These are data that change constantly, in fact it is enough for the external device to move that these data change (for example acceleration). I would only save these flow of data in an array

Comment: @mTv I want to print the data also in console log because the user shouldn't see these data

Comment: Don't think you explained it any better there. Basically just repeated the formulation you used in your question:S. I would need these points to help. 1. what does the data look like? 2. what do you want the data to end up looking like? 3. where do you want the data put? 4. example of your desired state.

Comment: Ok I edit my first post whit this answers :D Thank you for your help

Comment: @mTv Ok I have edited the message :)

Comment: So maybe do `this.setState({acc: [...this.state.acc, acc]})` in the function you pass to `monitorCharacteristicForService`? This just appends the data array you read to the existing state. Should end up with arrays with arrays that way.